# One step check for null value & emptiness of a string

Tags: java, string

I have a setter method.

Then when another (say generate) method is run, I need to check the value of my fields.
So in the case of String property, I need to know if it contains the value or if it was not set.
So it may be null, "" or something meaningful, there are 3 possibilities.
And it is rather boring to check first for a null value :

```
if (s != null)
```

then for an empty String

```
if (!s.isEmpty())
```

***is there a one-step check here? You can tell me that I can initialize my String field with an empty String. [ IS IT COMMON? ] But what if someone passes a null value to the setter method setS?
so do we always have to check if the Object value is null or not before doing something with that object?***

Well, yes a setter method can check it's values and also a getter method can return a non-null value if the field is null. But is it the only solution? It 's too much work in getters & setters for a programmer to do!

Comment: Yes Apache library.
Why, again, it is not in standart java distribution?

Comment: something to think about : null means not set, "" means set to empty.

Comment: Agree with Pat here.  It sometimes seems like this is just unnecessary book keeping but they are semantically different.  If the member is null, it means "has no value" whereas an empty string "has a value; an empty string".  It is common for methods to have different behavior (by design) based on this fact.

Comment: Sorry to spam the comments, but since it's somewhat related, you _can_ avoid the check-for-null-and-compare test on non-empty strings by having the string-literal do the test (string-literals are still Strings), e.g. "CheesySafeCompare".equals( someString ) works as you'd imagine but will _not_ throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 17):

Commons library, [StringUtils.isBlank()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-) or [StringUtils.isEmtpy()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence-).

isEmpty is equivalent to

```
s == null || s.length() == 0
```

isBlank is equivalent to

```
s == null || s.trim().length() == 0
```

Comment: little remark, what you described are isNotBlank & isNotEmpty :)

Answer (score 5):

```
if(s != null && !s.isEmpty()){
// this will work even if 's' is NULL
}
```

Comment: Although this prevents a null exception, this is not an equivalent test: the expression resolves to true if s is null. This is a null-safe way to test whether s contains an empty string, it does not test whether s is empty and **not null**. The difference is important!

Answer (score 4):

In the jakarta commons there is a StringUtils.isEmpty(String).

Answer (score 1):

use **org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils**, the method **StringUtils.isNotBlank** check both nullity and emptiness.

Answer (score 0):

Add maven dependency for [com.google.guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava)

Then in your code:

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;

if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(s)) {
  // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing android development, you can use:

```
TextUtils.isEmpty (CharSequence str)
```

Added in API level 1
Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.

Answer (score 0):

## Spring

Spring provides the class [org.springframework.util.StringUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html) which includes these relevant methods.

### [`hasText(String s)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#hasText(java.lang.CharSequence))

Returns true if and only if a `String` or `CharSequence` contains a character which is not a space.

Example:

```
 StringUtils.hasText(null) = false
 StringUtils.hasText("") = false
 StringUtils.hasText(" ") = false
 StringUtils.hasText("12345") = true
 StringUtils.hasText(" 12345 ") = true
```

### [`hasLength(String s)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#hasLength(java.lang.CharSequence))

Returns true if and only if a `String` or `CharSequence` contains any characters, spaces included.

Example:

```
 StringUtils.hasLength(null) = false
 StringUtils.hasLength("") = false
 StringUtils.hasLength(" ") = true
 StringUtils.hasLength("Hello") = true
```

In the case of the question, `hasText` would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

its not String. it should be Strings. as an example:

```
if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty()
```