# String null check

Tags: java

I have tried this for 2 hours , but I've given up. I am checking the value of a String this way:

```
if(value.equals("")||value.length()<0||value==null)
{
    value = "Anynomous"
}
```

But still the string is printing the value `null`.

Please see this program code here

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<%!
String value ;
%>

<%

value = (String)request.getAttribute("retunval");
System.out.println("Inside New fgdf JSP");
if(value.equals("")||value.length()<0||value==null)
value = "Anonymuos";


%>
Hello <%=value%>

<BR>
</BR>

<BR>
</BR>

<a href="Test.jsp">Try Again</a>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Try this: if (value==null || value.trim().length()==0 || value.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {value = "Anonymuos";}

Comment: Your order of conditions is wrong, First check `==null`. In this case if `value == null` you gets `NullPointerException` because of `value.equals("")` is executed first.

`if (value == null || value.length() == 0) value = "Anonymous";` should be OK. Likely you set value by string "null" somewhere somehow. For example `value = String.format("%s", somethingThatIsNull)` will result in `value == "null"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [One step check for null value & emptiness of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913280/one-step-check-for-null-value-emptiness-of-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think

> value = (String)request.getAttribute("retunval");

is returning you a "null" string.
When you try to do if tests that you have mentioned, it will return false because you are not checking

> value.equals("null")

so that's why you get output as null.

Comment: While the fix is correct, the diagnosis is not.  "null" is not a null string.  It's not returning a null string - it's returning the 4-character string "null".

Comment: all is well in this world and this is the accepted answer but i would just like to add here that while string checks its should always be "null".equals(value). i.e. the literal should always be the first operand.. that way you avoid NullPointerException

Comment: by null string, i also meant "null" string only and I think that is too obvious based on the check value.equals("null") I have talked about.

Answer (score 5):

Check whether `value` is `null` first. Otherwise `value.equals()` will throw a NullPointerException.

```
 if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
     value = "Anonymous";
 }
```

Comment: @ante.sabo: True, but it's probably actually better to use something like [Apache Commons `StringUtils#isBlank()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.String)) to cover that, as others suggested...

Answer (score 3):

First you need to reorder your if condition, otherwise you could run into NPEs.
Additionally, the string length can never be lower than 0, so that check is not needed:

```
value==null||value.equals("")
```

Alternatively, if you can use Apache Commons Lang you could use `StringUtils.isEmpty(value)` which handles all the relevant cases for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add

```
||value.equals("null")
```

Somewhere something already did a toString() on the null value.
Note the other answers as well - but this is the cause of the specific problem you're reporting.

So you'd end up with, as one option:

```
if ( value==null || value.isEmpty() || "null".equals(value) )
```

Because of the null-check, inverting the .equals() isn't necessary in this case - but it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: its still a good practice to always use a literal as the first operand in equals comparison

Answer (score 1):

```
if(value.equals("")||value.length()<0||value==null)
  value = "Anynomous"
```

The second and third condition can never evaluate to true!
(A String's length can never be less than zero, and if value was null, `value.equals("")` would have caused a `NullPointerException`)

try this instead:

```
if(value==null||"".equals(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

`value.length()<0` will never be true - use `value.length()==0` instead. However, in this case, the previous check (`value.equals("")`) is equivalent to this one, so you can omit it. Apart from this, the condition should detect empty/null strings (except that the null check should be first, to avoid dereferencing a null pointer).

Is it possible that `value` contains the text `"null"`?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the value of the string is 'null'? (That is, not null, but a string which reads 'null')

Answer (score 0):

Reorder as Thomas and ig0774 suggested or use the [`StringUtils.isEmpty()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) method of [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Comment: Using a third-party library for something as simple as checking for `null` seems a little superfluous to me.

Comment: Checking for `null` and _empty string_. I think the code is more readable with `StringUtils` and there are other useful method in this lib. With maven just a few clicks to import a dependency, it's a not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
   if(value == null || value.trim().length() <=0 || value.trim().equals("null")){
     value ="Ananymous";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the best condition to check for it

**if(value==null || value.trim().length()==0 || value.equals("null"))**

it also eliminate fact if value="   " contains spaces.